# which one is best React Native cli or React Expo for large eCommerce App

Tags: reactjs, react-native

we are planning to use react Native for our eCommerce app but i got confused which one to use need some best suggestion we have 3rd party Payment method

1. React Native CLI
2. React Expo

Which one to use & why ?

if we are using ReactNative Cli so we have to write separate code for android & ios or in one code both OS manage ?

Comment: I choose option 1, ReactNative CLI

Comment: React Native CLI is the best option.

Comment: @JebinBenny : can you please explain little more why we have to use ReactNative Cli rather than expo i am little new to this

Comment: @KishanBharda :  can you please explain little more why we have to use ReactNative Cli rather than expo i am little new to this

Comment: If you want to use native functionality of devices then React Native CLI provide better functionality. React Expo will not provide all the Native Functions compare to React Native CLI.

Comment: You will get more help for ReactNative CLI. And its very easy to customize.

Comment: @JebinBenny : if we are using ReactNative Cli so we have to write separate code for android & ios or in one code both OS manage

Answer (score 1):

Using Expo for building apps is much less time consuming and you get going in pretty fast as compare to React-Native CLI , React-Native CLI is much kind of manual,but while building with react native cli you get deep knowledge of what is going on while on the other hand expo makes it pretty fast.like in expo if you call in a function , you dont have to import it manually even while ejecting the app and building .apk its a straight forward process made for you. Talking of third party payments its not an issue in any of them....you can choose any one. i suggest you to use expo.